# Load Pandas dataframe into Hive with int64 datatype

Tags: pandas, hadoop, hive

I'm getting an error when loading a pandas dataframe that contains a column with a datatype as int64 into a hive table.

When I exclude the int64 datatypes the data loads to hive, but it fails when I include the data types. An extract of the data values for B and C are `12,12345678`

Pandas

```
df.dtypes
A    object
B    int64
C    int64
D    float6

df_s.to_parquet("data.parquet")
```

Hive

```
CREATE TABLE mytable( 
A string,
B int,
C int,
D string) 
PARTITIONED BY (RECORD_CREATE_DT date) 
STORED AS PARQUET

Load data inpath (<hdfs_path_of_file>) into table mytable partition (record_create_dt='9999-12-31');
```

Query

```
select * from mytable;
```

Error:

`Error: java.io.IOException: ... : java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable cannot be cast to org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable (state=,code=0)`

Error if hive table uses string instead of int
`Error: java.io.IOException: ... : java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Cannot inspect org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable (state=,code=0`

Comment: Going by https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Types#LanguageManualTypes-NumericTypes, Parquet's `Int64` maps to `BIGINT` SQL type.

Comment: Actually, that worked! I originally tried INT and string, but they failed and so I didn't even think about BIGINT. Thanks for the link as well

Comment: Also, for those interested... you need to map `float64` to `decimal`

Answer (score 0):

change datatype from int to bigint in the create table statement

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).